# How to capture output from PHP extension when using PHP-FPM

Tags: php, php-extension

I have a custom C extension loaded in my PHP and inside the extension there's a function does something like this

```
void a() {
    printf("abc");
}
```

I can call `a()` with no problem in CLI mode (command-line) and got the output `abc` as expected. But when i tried again in our Yii project in PHP-FPM mode，I couldn't get that output.

**What I am sure about is:**

- The extension is loaded.
- The function call is successfully made with no error.
- PHP output buffering is turned off. I called `ob_end_clean()` twice before calling `a()`, the first call return `true` and the second returned `false`.

**So my question is:**

Am I supposed to get output from extensions in PHP-FPM mode?

If so, how can I capture the output, or please shoot me some debugging advice.

Comment: When you say 'What I am sure about is:- The extension is loaded.' do you mean you have echoed phpinfo on one of the web pages under your yii project and found your extension.

Comment: @KamalSoni Yes. Actually there are several functions in the extension. They all worked properly in the Yii project except for the issue that i can't get the output made by `printf`

Comment: Ok Great @Lution I think you can debug by doing couple of things and it might help you. 1) Firstly I think your printf function signature does not look right. Should it just have one parameter or more. May be try print instead. 2) Create void b() {printf("abc");} and see if you get anything calling b instead of a. Also after each changes it is worth restarting php-fpm.

Answer (score 5):

When PHP runs as a webserver module, stdout is redirected to the terminal from which the webserver process was originally started. On production server such a terminal is not active, so any output that you send to stdout will be lost.

try  **php_printf()** function istead of printf() one

probably this article can help you https://devzone.zend.com/317/extension-writing-part-ii-parameters-arrays-and-zvals/